# is 'element.wait_until' broken in page_object 2.0.0?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

Using Watir 6.0.3, page object 2.0.0 and Ruby 2.1.9

As per latest watir and page-object changes changed below code to

```
wait_until(DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME.to_i, 'Login button not found when waiting for the login page to load') do
  login_element.visible?
end
```

**to**

```
message = "Login button not found when waiting for the login page to load"
login_element.wait_until(timeout: timeout, message: message, &:visible?)
```

but getting `undefined method 'zero?' for #<Hash:0x4991340> (NoMethodError)`error.

however if I get rid of page-object locator shown below Watir 'wait_until'works as expected.

```
message = "Login button not found when waiting for the login page to load"
browser.button(name: 'login').wait_until(timeout: 10, message: message, &:visible?)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Element#wait_until`](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/949cf84b3828cc3a7ed3fec52af808a7dab93c43/lib/page-object/platforms/watir/element.rb#L214-L216) method is defined as:

```
def wait_until(timeout=::PageObject.default_element_wait, message=nil, &block)
  Object::Watir::Wait.until(timeout: timeout, message: message, &block)
end
```

Notice that `timeout` and `message` are normal parameters rather than keyword arguments. As a result, the usage needs to be:

```
login_element.wait_until(timeout, message, &:visible?)
```

That said, `Element#wait_until` is still broken. The way that `Object::Watir::Wait.until` is called will result in a NoMethodError due to `object` being `nil` in the Watir method. Until a fix is released, you can monkey patch Page-Object using (included after you `require 'page-object'`):

```
module PageObject
  module Platforms
    module WatirWebDriver
      module Element
        def wait_until(timeout=::PageObject.default_element_wait, message=nil, &block)
          element.wait_until(timeout: timeout, message: message, &block)
        end
       end
     end
   end
 end
```